# useContext not working when calling component from another component that is having useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

The problem I am facing is:-

In my home page component, I have my code like:-

```
const { portfolios, getPortfolios } = useContext(PortfolioContext);
  
useEffect(() => {getPortfolios()}, []);

return (...)
```

When calling this component it works just fine, e.g. like when landing on home page all the portfolios are displayed correctly that means I get my portfolios and getPortfolios function from Context API
Also when I land on the home page from link (using react-router-dom), there is no problem

But, when coming from a page that shows details of the portfolio using a slug, code:-

```
const { slug } = useParams();
const { portfolios, getPortfolioFromSlug } = useContext(PortfolioContext);
  
useEffect(() => {getPortfolioFromSlug(slug)}, []);

return (...)
```

I still get my portfolio details correctly using the slug

But **now**, if I go from this portfolio details page to my home page (Both having the Context API) by clicking any of the links that use react-router-dom (e.g. from Navbar component), I get errors on console and nothing is displayed on the screen.

The errors I get are:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: portfolios.map is not a function
    at Portfolio (Portfolio.js:15:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)

The above error occurred in the <Portfolio> component:

    at Portfolio (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1315:56)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49405:5)
    at main
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49338:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48147:5)
    at PortfolioState (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1588:86)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

FYR, `portfolios.map` is used in the home page component which is rendered correctly if we reload the page after getting the error

The problem ONLY occurs when we get to that page from the portfolio details page

I am new to useContext and React and stuck at this problem,
I tried searching for the answer everywhere but couldn't get the answer, can you please help solve the problem,
Thank you!

////////////////////////EDIT///////////////////////////////////
Code for `getPortfolios()` and `getPortfolioFromSlug()` functions

```
const getPortfolios = async () => {
    // API Call
    const response = await fetch(`http://${host}:${port}/api/portfolios/getportfolios`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    setPortfolios(jsonResponse);
}

const getPortfolioFromSlug = async (slug) => {
    // API Call
    const response = await fetch(`http://${host}:${port}/api/portfolios/getportfolio/${slug}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    setPortfolios(jsonResponse);
}
```

Comment: Try using `console.log(portfolios)` on the home page.

Comment: What does `getPortfolioFromSlug` do? How does it store the fetched `portfolio`? In the `portfolios` property?

Comment: @AliNauman The `getPortfolioFromSlu`g calls the api for getting a portfolio by filtering using the slug, and it stores `portfolio` in a state using `useState` hook's `setPortfolio`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, it prints single object of the slug that was opened earlier, by doing that I came to know that after the state has been changed from the portfolio details page, it is not again changed in the home page's component but the `setPortfolio` function is already there in the `getPortfolios` function for that, so idk why still it does that

Comment: Does `getPortfolioFromSlug` also modify the `portfolio` property in the `PortfolioContext`? Looks like the property is initially an array, but becomes something else between navigating away from the home page and returning back to it from the portfolio details page

Comment: yes, it was initially array and then becomes object, also added both the functions in the question itself

Comment: @AliNauman Should I consider using different state variables for the portfolio object and for portfolios array?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be your issue. If `portfolios` is no longer an array, it won't have `map` method, and hence the error.

Comment: Yes, did the same thing, I was trying to change the type of portfolios from object to array again but don't know why it wasn't happening, now it works, Thanks a lot!